# How to display data from hash into a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a hash, which contains information like this

```
{"Bananas"=>2, "Apples"=>3}
```

This hash regularly updates, such as when a new fruit gets added and clicked on. The number is the number of times it is clicked on.

I want to display a table which basically shows the name and the number of clicks

Something like this

```
@hash.each do |hash|
   %tr
      %th hash.fruit_name
      %th hash.clicks
```

Now I don't have access to .fruit_name and .clicks, which is why I'm not doing it like that, but I want the same result but from the hash

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Hash#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Hash.html#method-i-each) passes `key` and `value` on iteration. In your case `key` is a `fruit_name` and `value` is a `clicks`:

```
@hash.each do |fruit_name, clicks|
   %tr
      %th fruit_name
      %th clicks
```